# Trouble updating mysql with PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, mysql-error-1064

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'High_Priority =
>   'NO', Private_Locate = 'NO', Ticket_Revision_Number = '1' ' at line 8'
>   in /home3/cmschu/public_html/pl/811/edit_ticket_submit.php:102 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /home3/cmschu/public_html/pl/811/edit_ticket_submit.php(102):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home3/cmschu/public_html/pl/811/edit_ticket_submit.php on line 102

when running the following PDO statement:

```
// configuration
include('811_common.php');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
// new data

$Member_Code = $_POST['Member_Code'];
$State = $_POST['State'];
$Ticket_Number = $_POST['Ticket_Number'];
$Start_Date  = $_POST['Start_Date'];
$Arrive = $_POST['Arrive'];
$Depart = $_POST['Depart'];

$COB01_WATER = $_POST['COB01_WATER'];
$COB01_SEWER = $_POST['COB01_SEWER'];
$COB01_STORM = $_POST['COB01_STORM'];
$COB01_LIGHTS = $_POST['COB01_LIGHTS'];
$COB01_HOURLY = $_POST['COB01_HOURLY'];
$COB01_SV = $_POST['COB01_SV'];
$COB01_ONCALL = $_POST['COB01_ONCALL'];

$NEWB01_POTABLE_WATER = $_POST['NEWB01_POTABLE_WATER'];
$NEWB01_REUSE_WATER = $_POST['NEWB01_REUSE_WATER'];
$NEWB01_DATA_COM = $_POST['NEWB01_DATA_COM'];
$NEWB01_SL = $_POST['NEWB01_SL'];

$Locate_Code = $_POST['Locate_Code'];
$Ticket_Status = $_POST['Ticket_Status'];
$Int_Note = $_POST['Int_Note'];
$Bill_Status = $_POST['Bill_Status'];
$High_Priority = $_POST['High_Priority'];
$Private_Locate = $_POST['Private_Locate'];
$Ticket_Revision_Number = $_POST['Ticket_Revision_Number'];

$db_ID = $_POST['db_ID'];


// query
$sql="UPDATE billing
        SET  Member_Code = :Member_Code, State = :State, Ticket_Number = :Ticket_Number, Start_Date = :Start_Date, Arrive = :Arrive, Depart = :Depart, 
        COB01_WATER = :COB01_WATER, COB01_STORM = :COB01_STORM, COB01_SEWER = :COB01_SEWER, COB01_LIGHTS = :COB01_LIGHTS, COB01_HOURLY = :COB01_HOURLY, COB01_SV = :COB01_SV, COB01_ONCALL = :COB01_ONCALL,
        NEWB01_POTABLE_WATER = :NEWB01_POTABLE_WATER, NEWB01_REUSE_WATER = :NEWB01_REUSE_WATER, NEWB01_DATA_COM = :NEWB01_DATA_COM, NEWB01_SL = :NEWB01_SL, 
        Locate_Code = :Locate_Code, Ticket_Status = :Ticket_Status, Int_Note = :Int_Note, Bill_Status = :Bill_Status, High_Priority = :High_Priority, Private_Locate = :Private_Locate, Ticket_Revision_Number = :Ticket_Revision_Number

        WHERE db_ID LIKE :db_ID ";  

    $q = $db1->prepare($sql);

    $q->bindValue(':Member_Code', $Member_Code, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':State', $State, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':Ticket_Number', $Ticket_Number, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':Start_Date', $Start_Date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':Arrive', $Arrive, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':Depart', $Depart, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $q->bindValue(':COB01_WATER', $COB01_WATER, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':COB01_SEWER', $COB01_SEWER, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':COB01_STORM', $COB01_STORM, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':COB01_LIGHTS', $COB01_LIGHTS, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':COB01_HOURLY', $COB01_HOURLY, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':COB01_SV', $COB01_SV, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':COB01_ONCALL', $COB01_ONCALL, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $q->bindValue(':NEWB01_POTABLE_WATER', $NEWB01_POTABLE_WATER, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':NEWB01_REUSE_WATER', $NEWB01_REUSE_WATER, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':NEWB01_DATA_COM', $NEWB01_DATA_COM, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':NEWB01_SL', $NEWB01_SL, PDO::PARAM_STR);


    $q->bindValue(':Locate_Code', $Locate_Code, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':Ticket_Status', $Ticket_Status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':Int_Note', $Int_Note, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':Bill_Status', $Bill_Status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':High_Priority', $High_Priority, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':Private_Locate', $Private_Locate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':Ticket_Revision_Number', $Ticket_Revision_Number, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':db_ID', $db_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $q->execute();

?></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

`HIGH_PRIORITY` is a MySQL Reserved Word.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

If you want to use that as an identifier (e.g. the name of a column), references to the identifier must be properly escaped. The normal MySQL pattern is to enclose the identifier in backtick character. For example:

```
     , Bill_Status            = :Bill_Status
     , `High_Priority`        = :High_Priority
     , Private_Locate         = :Private_Locate
```